# Why when assigning a value to a pixel in image it gives garbage in Python

Tags: python, image, filter

I'm implementing Average Filter on an image but when i'm assigning a value for a pixel it gives a lot of garbage
Here's my code

```
def AvergaeFilter():
    ImageToWork = cv2.imread('D:\Y3T2\Brain Tumor\BrainTumourGray.jpg')
    w = ImageToWork.shape[0]
    h = ImageToWork.shape[1]
    for i in range(2,700):
        for j in range(2,700):
            Total = ((ImageToWork[i][j])+(ImageToWork[i][j+1])+(ImageToWork[i+1][j-1])+(ImageToWork[i+1][j])+((ImageToWork[i+1][j+1])+(ImageToWork[i][j-1])+(ImageToWork[i-1][j+1])+(ImageToWork[i-1][j-1])+(ImageToWork[i-1][j])))/9
            ImageToWork[i][j] = Total
    cv2.imwrite('D:\Y3T2\Brain Tumor\BrainGrayTest.jpg', ImageToWork)
```

When i print(Total) it gives a value but when i run the code for an image it gives a garbage like this.

[image]

Comment: One problem is that you're trying to change the image in-place, so updating one pixel affects the computation of the next pixel.  You should store the results into a new array, so that you never look at any new pixel values until you've created the entire new image.

Comment: When i tested for assigning the value to a new image it also gives the same garbage :/

Comment: Yeah, that may not be the only problem, but it was definitely *a* problem.

Comment: Ok, here's a question:  Are the values in `ImageToWork` integers?  And are you using Python 3?  If so, then the result of the divide-by-9 is a float, which might possibly be changing the interpretation (I really don't know).  If you want to force the result to an integer, use `//` instead of `/` when dividing.

Comment: OMG i'm really sorry i posted a wrong image, but now i updated it so please take a look. i tried your operators // and the output was as the same but after i update the photo take a look.I'm very sorry
And yes i'm using python 3

Comment: And you tried storing the new values into a new array, then copying them back to the original array only after all of the new values had been computed?

Comment: Yes i did that :/

Comment: Ok, sorry I don't think I can diagnose it from this.  I would need to see the actual data to know what's happening.  It might help to pick a single pixel, look at the 9 pixel values surrounding it, then see if the stored value matches the average of those 9 values.

Comment: I tested it myself, i captured the data ((ImageToWork[i][j])+(ImageToWork[i][j+1]) and so on.. ) and print each one in a line and then print the (Total) it gives a right answer as i calculated it on my calculator. but i don't know what is wrong with the code when assigning values to the image :/

Comment: If you have improved your code to store the results into a new, empty image rather than back into the original image, please edit your question and add in your latest code.

Comment: I solved it today but unfortunatly it doesn't give the same result exactly as built-in function but it's okay and good to work.
@MarkSetchell Thanks. Please check now if it's good or need to be edited

Comment: You can move the first `temp=0` down between `for j ...` and `for k...` and remove the second `temp=0`.

Comment: @MohamedWael If you have a solution then post an answer in the answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated Code [Working now]

```
def AverageFilter():
ImageToWork = cv2.imread('D:\Y3T2\Brain Tumor\BrainGrayNoise.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ImageToOut = ImageToWork.copy()
height = ImageToWork.shape[0]
width = ImageToWork.shape[1]
for i in np.arange(3, height-3):
    for j in np.arange(3, width-3):    
        Temp = 0  
        for k in np.arange(-3, 4):
            for l in np.arange(-3, 4):
                Value = (ImageToWork.item(i+k, j+l))
                Temp = Temp + Value
            Temp = Temp//9
        ImageToOut.itemset((i,j), Temp)
        #Temp = 0

cv2.imwrite('D:\Y3T2\Brain Tumor\BrainGrayAverageFilter.jpg', ImageToOut)
```

You can replace